# Q: Pass strings between windows in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, variables

I am trying to pass data from one window to another and then use it in a the second window. i have tried the following

```
string sConnect = "Sample Text"
Window2 win2 = new Window2(sConnect)
win2.Show();
```

and then in the second window i did this

```
public Window2(string connect)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string connection = connect
        }
```

but then i cant use the data in that window for some reason
i would appriciate some help

Comment: `string connection = connect` is a local variable. Use a field instead.

Comment: connection has scope to the constructor method only. Add a private string connection; to the class. Outside that constructor method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments are correct. Change

```
    public Window2(string connect)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string connection = connect
    }
```

to a public or private field, e.g.

```
    public string connection; 
    public Window2(string connect)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection = connect
    }
```

.. other methods in Window2 will now be able to access "connection".